# I'm trying to dedicate a channel to only sending pictures and reddit links

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im Having some trouble trying to dedicate it.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.author === client) return;
  if (message.channel.id === "605839623372931093") {
  if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    if (!message.attachments.every(attachIsImage) || !message.content.includes("https://www.reddit.com/")) {
      (bulkDelete(message))
      (message.channel.send("This channel Only Supports Picture Messages or Reddit Links!"));
}}}});
```

It is worth noting that my code doesn't give out any errors, it just doesnt do anything.

If you would like to know more, just ask me and I'm willing to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unnecessary `if` statements in your code, assuming your the `channel` ID you're providing is correct this should work:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.author === client) return;
  if (message.channel.id === "605839623372931093") {
    if (message.attachments.size === 0 || !message.content.includes('https://www.reddit.com/')) {
      bulkDelete(message)
      message.channel.send("This channel Only Supports Picture Messages or Reddit Links!");
    }
  }
});
```